# How to make subscript enclosed in empheq environment

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, beamer

I was trying to use `pandoc` to generate beamer slides with equation highlighted using *empheq* package, then I have this problem of equations with subscripts are not able to convert to proper latex code. I made a minimal case here, and hopefully anyone of you out there can help me to get the subscript correctly converted. Thanks in advance for your help.

I have a minimalist markdown file `buggy.md` here that reproduced my issue. The file contains two coloured equations, one without subscript and one with subscript:

```
\begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{equation*}
   c
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{equation*}
   c_n
\end{empheq}
```

Then, I tried to convert it into `buggy.tex` file using `pandoc` using the following command

```
pandoc buggy.md -o buggy.tex
```

The results of the two equations are very different. The one without subscript are converted to `tex` without any issue, but the one with subscript is totally wrong. I have the content of the `buggy.tex` here:

```
\begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{equation*}
   c
\end{empheq}

\textbackslash{}begin\{empheq\}{[}box=\mymath{]}\{equation*\} c\_n
\textbackslash{}end\{empheq\}
```

I would expect that after the `pandoc` conversion, the output `buggy.tex` should be the same as the original `buggy.md`, but it is not the case. The same issue happened if the environment used is `align*` or `eqnarray*`.

How do I get back my coloured equation with subscript? Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this, the issue has likely been resolved in newer pandoc versions.

If you are using pandoc 2.0 or later, then you can also explicitly mark your LaTeX snippets as such:

````
```{=latex}
\begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{equation*}
   c
\end{empheq}
```
````

See the manual for the [`raw_attribute` extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_attribute) for details.

Comment: Yes, it works using the `raw_attribute extension`. Thanks a lot.

My `pandoc` version is 2.2.3. I will try to upgrade and see if the problem will go away after upgrade.